# How to make these scale right in CSS (block with horizontal and vertical attachés)

Tags: html, css, scaling

I feel like a competent programmer, but I am terrible at CSS.  I read about float and clear and display: inline-block and can understand the material, but I still can't apply this to my own designs.  I think my incompetence tends to frustrate me, which tends to become counterproductive quickly.  That being said, nothing should stop you from trying (!) so...

My layout is essentially:

```
 _____________  
|         | v |
|         | e |
| big_div | r |
|         | t |
|_________|___|
|   lower     |
|_____________|
```

I want the div labeled `vert` and the div labeled `lower` to "stick" to the big div.  To nestle together like cats and mice in winter.  The following accomplishes that if the sizes are fixed:

```
<div id="big_div" style="float:left"></div>

<div id="vert" style="float:left"></div>

<div id="lower" style="clear: left"></div>
```

This shows exactly what I want, but as I said, only if I fix the sizes.  **How do I make them scale with the growth of big_div (since its contents are of arbitrary size?**
I want them to scale with the size of big_div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container around big_div and vert and apply Faux Columns to it.  lower should then handle itself either inside or outside of the container.  Let me know if you need an example.

Example added: http://imaginekitty.com/cssExamples/cats/cats.html

Comment: Please provide an example.  I think I get what you mean, but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: @sova: by 'Faux Columns' he of course is referring to a "fake column", which means applying a repeat-y background to the larger element (or a container of both) that gives the _appearance_ that they are equal height.  For true equal height columns, check out http://pmob.co.uk/pob/equal-columns.htm (Equalising Columns Without Images section).

Comment: Extremely ugly example added to answer above.   ;)

Comment: dude, you are awesome!  No need to work so hard for a green check from me, but I certainly appreciate it brother!  Also, page title is made of win

Comment: HAHA, I though you'd like that page title. :D

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS instead of using `width` to fix the size, use `min-width` and let it grow naturally.